# can any one explain what is this dlpack and python api standard?

Tags: python, arrays

I am implementing a new tensor backend with numpy, tensorflow / pytorch,
What is this dlpack and python api standard?

If any one explain more will be a lot of help!
thanks in advance.

what i got about the python api standard is it contains methods that should be implemented by any new tensor(array) library (standards to be followed by a tensor library)
and about dlpack that it is for data exchange.
how can we implement dlpack in a new library?

Comment: Check out [this page](https://dmlc.github.io/dlpack/latest/python_spec.html), which explains DLPack is a standard for "the memory layout of dense, strided, n-dimensional arrays."